# do I need to have a credit card on file in order to get current usage info on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have a hobby-dev account, and it says "Not Available" next to "Current Usage" on my account page.  Do I need to enter credit card info in order to get usage info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the [account page](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account) in Heroku dashboard, there is a billing section where you can enter credit card info.

Comment: Right, but my question is whether entering credit card info is a pre-condition to being able to see my usage info.

Comment: I see, I supposed so. That field shows the amount payable to Heroku, so "Not Available" make sense if credit card info is missing.

Comment: I entered credit card info and usage info is now available, so looks like that's the prerequisite.